# Operator precedence and associativity with unary operator java

Tags: java, operators, operator-precedence

```
int x = 2;
int p = x-- + 3 * x;
```

This is printing 5 . Can someone explain this behaviour , multiply operator has higher precedence than add operator . Given this it should have printed 8